# App ready for sale but not available in app store

Tags: ios, app-store

I got two of my apps approved yesterday night, one was a free app and another was the paid version of the same app. Today morning I released the apps, and both the apps are ready for sale, but only the free version is appearing in the app store where as the paid version is no where to be seen.
[Here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/calkify-calculations-simplified/id1019180817?ls=1&mt=8) is the link to the free version. But I cant find the paid version on the app store, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the availability date of your app in the `Pricing section`. It might not have been set to `31 july 2015`. If it is then sometimes after your app gets `Ready for Sale` it might take some time before it actually shows up in searches.

Comment: I checked the availability it was set to 10th august, I have changed it to 31st july now.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah takes sometime more than a day for the App to show up on App Store. But better contact Apple in that case.

Check the App Store email after App is Ready for Sale
[image: Check the App Store email after App is Ready for Sale]